# Run a Process in case of Unhandled Exception

Tags: vb.net

I need to run a process in case of any unhandled exceptions occurring.

So is there a way to catch all exceptions in the application and create a process in this case?

UPDATE (Tim): It's a single form VB.NET application, with several functions each of them throws an exception for a different reason every time so I can't find a solution other than doing it globally on this form or application

Comment: What kind of application?  WinForm?  ASP.NET? You should be able to create a global exception handler, but the specifics vary depending on the application.  Or are you wanting to catch unhandled exceptions outside the scope of the application?  That's an entirely different situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(For WinForms) You need to subscribe to the ThreadException event (you can do this from your 'Main' method):

```
AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf OnThreadException
```

The signature for OnThreadException is:

```
Sub OnThreadException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal t As System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please explain a little but more how to to the subscribe part.

and regarding the Sub should I put it in the Form or somewhere else?

Comment: You need to disable "Activate application framework" in your project settings. You then create a new module and put a `Sub Main()` into it. Select this sub as your project's starting sub and run your application from there.

Comment: To subscribe, you're just specifying a method (I used "OnThreadException", but you can call it anything) that will be invoked when the event (System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException) happens.  You can put the method anywhere you want - you may want to create a class for it and then instantiate that class and pass the instance's method - e.g., Dim myInstance As New UnexpectedExceptions & AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf myInstance.OnThreadException.

Comment: @Jens: You don't need to disable the VB application framework - just have the AddHandler somewhere when the main form starts up.

Comment: True, I answered his follow up question regarding the Sub Main()

Comment: it worked, thanks!
Added the AddHandler in the Form Load

and created the sub and added desired code there

No need to create a new module or changing anything in settings